# Supervisor Program Forking to a Multi-threaded Child

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

First off, allow me to describe my scenario:

I developed a supervisory program on Linux that forks and then uses execv(), in the child process, to launch my multi-threaded application. The supervisory program is acting as a watchdog to the multi-threaded application. If the multi-threaded application does not send a SIGUSR1 signal to the supervisor after a period of time then the supervisory program will kill the child using the pid_t from the fork() call and repeat the process again.

Here is the code for the Supervisory Program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cerrno>
time_t heartbeatTime;

void signalHandler(int sigNum)
{
    //std::cout << "Signal (" << sigNum << ") received.\n";

    time(&heartbeatTime);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t cpid, ppid;
    int result = 0;
    bool programLaunched = false;
    time_t now;
    double timeDiff;
    int error;
    char ParentID[25];
    char *myArgv[2];

    // Get the Parent Process ID
    ppid = ::getpid();
    // Initialize the Child Process ID
    cpid = 0;
    // Copy the PID into the char array
    sprintf(ParentID, "%i", ppid);
    // Set up the array to pass to the Program
    myArgv[0] = ParentID;
    myArgv[1] = 0;

    // Print out of the P PID
    std::cout << "Parent ID: " << myArgv[0] << "\n";

    // Register for the SIGUSR1 signal
    signal(SIGUSR1, signalHandler);
    // Register the SIGCHLD so the children processes exit fully
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

    // Initialize the Heart Beat time
    time(&heartbeatTime);

    // Loop forever and ever, amen.
    while (1)
    {
        // Check to see if the program has been launched
        if (programLaunched == false)
        {
            std::cout << "Forking the process\n";
            // Fork the process to launch the application
            cpid = fork();
            std::cout << "Child PID: " << cpid << "\n";
        }

        // Check if the fork was successful
        if (cpid < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error in forking.\n";
            // Error in forking
            programLaunched = false;
        }
        else if (cpid == 0)
        {
            // Check if we need to launch the application
            if (programLaunched == false)
            {
                // Send a message to the output
                std::cout << "Launching Application...\n";
                // Launch the Application
                result = execv("./MyApp", myArgv);

                std::cout << "execv result = " << result << "\n";
                // Check if the program launched has failed
                if (result != -1)
                {
                    // Indicate the program has been launched
                    programLaunched = true;
                    // Exit the child process
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Child process terminated; bad execv\n";
                    // Flag that the program has not been launched
                    programLaunched = false;
                    // Exit the child process
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        // In the Parent Process
        else
        {
            // Get the current time
            time(&now);

            // Get the time difference between the program heartbeat time and current time
            timeDiff = difftime(now, heartbeatTime);

            // Check if we need to restart our application
            if ((timeDiff > 60) && (programLaunched == true))
            {
                std::cout << "Killing the application\n";
                // Kill the child process
                kill(cpid, SIGINT);
                // Indicate that the process was ended
                programLaunched = false;
                // Reset the Heart Beat time
                time(&heartbeatTime);
                return -1;
            }

            // Check to see if the child application is running
            if (kill(cpid, 0) == -1)
            {
                // Get the Error
                error = errno;
                // Check if the process is running
                if (error == ESRCH)
                {
                    std::cout << "Process is not running; start it.\n";
                    // Process is not running.
                    programLaunched = false;
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Child process is running
                programLaunched = true;
            }
        }
        // Give the process some time off.
        sleep(5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This approach worked fairly well until I ran into a problem with the library I was using. It didn't like all of the killing and it basically ended up tying up my Ethernet port in an endless loop of never releasing - not good.

I then tried an alternative method. I modified the supervisory program to allow it to exit if it had to kill the multi-threaded application and I created a script that will launch the supervisor program from crontab. I used a shell script that I found on Stackoverflow.

```
#!/bin/bash
#make-run.sh
#make sure a process is always running.

export DISPLAY=:0 #needed if you are running a simple gui app.

process=YourProcessName
makerun="/usr/bin/program"

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $process > /dev/null
then
    exit
else
    $makerun &
fi

exit
```

I added it to crontab to run every minute. That was very helpful and it restarted the supervisory program which in turn restarted multi-threaded application but I noticed a problem of multiple instances of the multi-threaded application being launched. I'm not really sure why this was happening.

I know I'm really hacking this up but I'm backed into a corner with this implementation. I'm just trying to get it to work.

Suggestions?

Comment: For one thing, if `makerun` is already running, you don't want to start another `makerun`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Isn't that what this script is checking? I modified this script to be:`process=AppName
makerun="/home/root/AppName"`

Comment: "I noticed a problem of multiple instances of the multi-threaded application being launched". Without your supervisory code we can not tell whether that really is a result of the cron or whether your supervisor is launching multiple instances of the multi-threaded application for some reason.

Comment: @kaylum I updated the question.

Comment: do not use tabs for indenting.  because each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Suggest using 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows for many indent levels across the page.

Comment: the statements like: `std::cin` are not in the C language, please remove the `c` tag.

Comment: the signature for the main() function has two parameters that are not being used.  This cause the compiler to output two warning messages.  Fix thiis by replacing the signature with: `int main( void )`

Comment: the posted code seems to be missing the required #include statements.  Please edit the posted code (with comments about the edit, in the code) so the code cleanly compiles.  WIthout those required/referenced header files, the compiler produces dozens of error and warning messages.

Comment: @user3629249 I removed the tag and added the include files.

Comment: a few corrections to the list of header files: 
`#include <stdio.h>  --> cstdio`
`#include <stdlib.h> --> cstdlib`

`#include <signal.h> --> csignal`

Comment: the man page for `signal()` says the behaviour is erratic and should use `sigaction()` instead

Comment: the posted code is not using the results of a call to `fork()` correctly in the child process.   The `execv()` function NEVER returns, unless the function itself failed.   A child process should always use `exit()` rather than `return`.  The signalhandler function should check which signal type was received, so it only updates the time value when a user signal (from the child) is received

Comment: the second argument passed to `execv()` is a pointer to an array of pointers to strings.    `myArgv[0] = ParentID;  myArgv[1] = 0;`  ( BTW: a 0 is not necessarily a NULL, especially on 64bit architectures..)

Comment: @user3629249 Some of my other C++ files from my Multi-threaded application are using the standard C header files and not the C++ ones. Would that cause any kind of problem? I'll give the `sigaction()` a try. ParentID was a char array. Am I setting up the second variable incorrectly? How can I fix it?

Comment: using the C header files rather than the C++ header files, means the system functions associated with those C header files will be used rather than C++ functions. (although, very often the C++ function is just a wrapper for the C function, but not always.

Comment: the second entry in the myarg[] (I.E. the last entry) should be NULL, not 0

Comment: If your other C++ source files in the project are #include'ing the C header files rather than the c++ header files, I suggest you (now that you know) fix those other source files.